# limit Markdown in Django

Tags: python, django, markdown

I am using markdown on the comments system in my blog developed using django 
I want to limit the possible format to accept just a basic one  (with **bold, italic, link and code**)

How do I set Markdown to do this ?

if this is not possible using markdown so any alternatives ? 
PS : i am using the default django app 'django.contrib.markup'

here is the actual code i am using on my template:

```
          <div class="comment-content>
            <p>
             {% load markup %}
             {{ comment.comment|markdown:"safe" }}
            </p>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would depend on which markdown plugin you're using there are many out there from a quick google search.

You'll have to either find documentation online for the specific one you are using, or perhaps look through the source and if it's open source modify it if you have to.
Or just find another one that allows that functionality.

**edit:**
Seems that django uses python-markdown(http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/), from a quick look it doesn't seem to support specifying only specific formatting options. However it seems to be easily extensible, so if you write an extension you can use it in django like this:

```
{{ string|markdown:"extension_name,extension2,etc..." }}
```

Comment: i am using the standard one 'django.contrib.markup'. i dont want to do it this way by changing the source codes, i want some thing more dynamic and customizable

Comment: Yes the django one uses python-markdown: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/markup/. The vanilla version doesn't support what you are looking for.

Comment: I haven't used any of these personally. But one option is to use something like `from django.utils.html import strip_tags` and then strip the unwanted html tags after the markdown has inserted them? Template version is `{{ value|removetags:"div span b"|safe }}`. However you'd lose the markdown characters that originally represented those.

Comment: thanx this was what i want {{comment.comment|markdown|removetags:"div span b h1 img h2 h3"|safe}}

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Bleach](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bleach) and write a template tag to strip out the tags you don't want.

For example, to allow only bold and italic:

```
@register.filter
def limit_markdown(comment):
    comment = bleach.clean(comment, tags=['b', 'i', 'em'], strip=True)
    return comment
```

Then in your template, you could use it as:

```
{{ comment.comment|markdown|limit_markdown|safe }}
```